# Connect TWO separate users account (same windows) to TWO different wireless network and work simultaneously

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, wireless-networking, user-accounts

I login to different accounts and switch between them doing different work at the same time, each account has its own profile and settings. These accounts share the HW resources like the built-in WiFi adapter. (OS Windows 8.1)

I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to a separate WiFi network from each account and work on both at the same time? using "Edup wireless USB adapter" for one account and the built-in for the other one. "without disconnect when I switch between the accounts?" - **Real-time and simultaneously**..

I'm trying to do that as I need to work from two different real IP at the same time, It'll be great and better than getting another laptop!

Note: *If you know a way to run this over Linux please don't hesitate to let me know.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common WiFi HW allows only for one connection at a time. A second WiFi adapter also won't get you too far:

Because the Operating System handles network traffic for all users, you may have to set up Per-User Routing, which is not exactly trivial (and the Windows/Linux choice makes a big difference there). This depends on your exact requirements; in some cases, an application-level distinction (via a configured Proxy) may do. But in many other cases, this won't be sufficient.

You don't sound like a networking expert. For an easy fully flavoured solution, I would set up one or two Virtual Machines.

From there, you have at least two options. Use only one WLAN, have the two WiFi Routers in the same LAN, and configure the default gateway in one machine manually to use the other router. Or you can eliminate the need for the second router completely by using a VPN to a gateway with a separate address.

Comment: I though there is a way to make the OS load a separate kernel space for each user and so handle a different HW device like the WiFi.

but the VMware, smart!

I'll give it a try and install machine over the primary OS.

Thank you :)

Comment: @AymanYounis: Separate kernel space for each user is somewhat easier in Linux, as is per-user routing. I've never attempted the latter in Windows, though tbh if it's a limited range of applications, per user proxy settings might be an easy workaround

Comment: I installed VMWare and windows 10 over the host windows 8.1, but it doesn't work, the VM can't work with the USB WiFI, even after disabling and uninstalling it from the Host!

Comment: @qasdfdsaq How will the user proxy help me to connect to two different wireless network to get two different real IP, can you explain this way if you think it'll work please?

If I gave up of windows, I'll try Linux.

Comment: Done, It's working now on the VMWare windows 10 and host windows 8.1, Thank you :)

Comment: @AymanYounis Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: @AymanYounis: The idea is set applications under user 1 to use a proxy on network 1, and those running under user 2 to use a proxy on network 2. Obviously this isn't network-level and only application level.